# Update dependencies on package.json based on package-lock.json

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

After almost a day of battle with discrepancies between `package.json` based on `package-lock.json` I finally made my project to run again (on Node 10) and I want to keep it in that way.

I want to update my `package.json` to contain the versions listed in `package-lock.json`. Is there an automatic way to do this? I can find any about it (or maybe I am looking for the wrong keywords)

Comment: Are you commiting your package-lock to version control? Because that's precisely what it's there for.

Comment: Yes I am. And I had trusted it but the only way to be able to run this project again was to delete `package-lock.json` and do `npm install`. I do not want this to happen again.